# CSS :not() how do I not select any element if it's a child of container with class="foo"?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create CSS code in SASS for a WordPress site where I've written my styles for content that is displayed in a container called ".entry-content".

I've created some custom blocks and given them a standard class throughout  called ".mnk-block".

What I want is, elements inside my blocks (such as an `<h2>` or `<p>` for example), don't use the parent ".entry-content" styles if placed inside that container. I thought using the `:not()` pseudo class would be the appropriate route, but it's just not working.

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <h2>My title</h2>
  <div class="mnk-block">
    <h2>My block title</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

In sass I've written the code like this

```
.mnk-block {
  h2 {
    color: red;
  }
}
.entry-content {
  h2:not(.mnk-block h2) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

But this ends up not selecting anything at all. My ".mnk-block" displays correctly because it uses its styles declared elsewhere, but my ".entry-content" styles don't get applied anywhere.

I then tried this:

```
.mnk-block {
  h2 {
    color: red;
  }
}

.entry-content {
  :not(.mnk-block) {
    h2 {
      color: blue;
   }
  }
```

But this selected anything matching within `.entry-content`, overriding or clashing with my styles for my `.mnk-block` CSS.

How do I declare styles that DON'T get applied to my specific class? This is really confusing me - had a hard time explain it here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The **order** of the CSS also matters.

Since snippets here won't accept SASS, I am using regular CSS: You can omit the `:not` if you first define a rule for `h2` (or any other element)  within `.entry-content` and then add a rule for `h2` as a child of `.mnk-block` which will overwrite the previous one:

```css
.entry-content h2 {
  color: blue;
}
.mnk-block h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <h2>My title</h2>
  <div class="mnk-block">
    <h2>My block title</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I commented below that's a good point that didn't occur to me, you've both stated the same (correct) point. But how to do it by not selecting child elements using :not()? (see comment I left on @Alan Lins reply) thank you!

Comment: Well, `.entry-content :not(.mnk-block) h2` would be a valid selector, but the problem about it is: In this case there *has*  to be *some* element between `.entry-content ` and `h2` - it would not apply to an `h2` which is a *direct* child of `.entry-content`. So you might use  `.entry-content :not(.mnk-block) h2,  .entry-content > h2 { ... } `, but I doubt if that's less complicated

Comment: OK thank you, I think instead of making these simpler I've just complicated it with trying to use :not() - I'll use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I will use example in pure css to explain it. Css gives priority to last instruction declared. So, if you move the ".mnk-block" to bottom it will override the entry-content h2 within .mnk-block. If you try the code below the entry-content h2 will be blue, while the mnk-block h2 will be red

```css
.entry-content h2{
    color: blue;
}

.mnk-block h2{
    color: red;  
}
```

However, you use this code below, everything will be blue, because the last instruction was the entry-content h2

```css
.mnk-block h2{
    color: red;  
}

.entry-content h2{
    color: blue;
}
```

Also, if you want to apply only for the first child h2 of entry-content and present all the nested children, you can use the >.

```css
.entry-content > h2{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That's a good point that didn't occur to me, as I was getting lost in trying to understand the :not() pseudo class. However how would I use :not() to NOT apply the styles in the child? I say this because we have a lot of blocks that we write and it seems more time consuming to re-declare all of the styles in these child elements to override them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

**CSS**

```css
.mnk-block h2{
  color: red;  
}
.entry-content:not(h2){
  color: blue;
}
```

**SCSS**

```
.mnk-block h2{
  color: red;  
}
.entry-content:not(h2){
  color: blue;
}
```

*Both are same*